# couldn't find or load main class

Tags: java

I placed my Java code to    the `bin`folder and try to run the code.   The command `javac Project.java` terminated successfully, but the command `java Project` throws the error

> couldn't find or load main class Project

This is my code:

```
Public class project {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code to share on this? Even if it is just your project folder structure

Comment: Why don't you use google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: Public class project {public static void main(String args[]){}} this is all code

Comment: Project file and Project class, otherwise it would throw other error

Comment: I have read all on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean but it didn't change

Comment: Which IDE / editor do you use? Eclipse? IntelliJ? Netbeans? Or just notepad or similar?

Comment: I use as editor far manager

Answer (score 2):

You've got your error because of wrong syntax. Of course, java can't find Project class, there's no such thing declared. This is a correct declaration:

```
  public class Project {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
    }
```

Note, that in Java class names start with upper-case letter, and access modifiers - with lower, like **public**, **private**, etc. I strongly suggest you to read [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) before writing any code.

If you're getting error like

> couldn't find or load main class Project

there is a chance that the "current" directory is not in your classpath ( where java looks for .class definitions ), so you need to put in on the classpath with `-cp` option (as it mentioned by @Nikhil B). Note, that doing

> javac -classpath "c:\java\jdk1.7.0.45"\bin" Project.java

which you posted in comments to his answer isn't correct. You should tell java interpreter where to find .class files, not java compiler (+ as I see, you've compiled your .java file just fine).

So, put the directory which contains .class file to a classpath somehow like this:

```
[root@crmdev clarify]# pwd //shows current directory
/home/clarify
[root@crmdev clarify]# javac Project.java //compiles .java file
[root@crmdev clarify]# ls Project.*  //here are my test files for your case
Project.class  Project.java
[root@crmdev clarify]# java -cp . Project "hello, @user5779261" //executing test code
hello, @user5779261
```

Comment: Changed the code according to convention, the problem has not disappeared

Comment: @user5779261 updated my answer, feel free to try the solution

Answer (score 1):

Run the java command with classpath option and it should run. (and change the class name to project from Project)

java -classpath "path to bin directory in double quotes" project

Comment: javac -classpath "c:\java\jdk1.7.0.45"\bin" Project.java

Comment: Javac: no source files